# Excel VBA compare column data copy row

Tags: vba, excel, comparison

Okay so I managed to work out this code somehow with help from many of the coding experts here. I need to create a macro that compares data in two worksheets.

In both of my worksheets, there is a column named "eRequest ID", I have to copy the rows of records that **DO NOT** have an "eRequest ID" in **BOTH FILES**.

The code i worked out now copies recrods that have an "eRequest ID" in **EITHER FILES**. So logically speaking i have to "negate" the IF condition in my code below, but I have no idea how to do it as I'm a total beginner at coding, VBA included.

```
 Sub compareAndCopy()
   Dim lastRowE As Integer
   Dim lastRowF As Integer
   Dim lastRowM As Integer
   Dim foundTrue As Boolean

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    lastRowE = Sheets("JULY15Release_Master Inventory").Cells(Sheets("JULY15Release_Master Inventory").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    lastRowF = Sheets("JULY15Release_Dev status").Cells(Sheets("JULY15Release_Dev status").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    lastRowM = Sheets("Mismatch").Cells(Sheets("Mismatch").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To lastRowE
    foundTrue = False
    For j = 1 To lastRowF

    If Sheets("JULY15Release_Master Inventory").Cells(i, 2).Value = Sheets   ("JULY15Release_Dev status").Cells(j, 7).Value Then
        foundTrue = False
        Exit For
    End If

    Next j

    If Not foundTrue Then
    Sheets("JULY15Release_Master Inventory").Rows(i).Copy Destination:= _
    Sheets("Mismatch").Rows(lastRowM + 1)
    lastRowM = lastRowM + 1

    End If


    Next i

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    End Sub
```

Forgive my poor formatting.. I'm very new to stackoverflow as well.

One more thing, I just realized that this code only copies rows from `Sheets("JULY15Release_Master Inventory")` It doesnt copy rows from `Sheets("JULY15Release_Dev status")` even if there is only one "eRequest ID" for that data.

Comment: your `foundTrue` variable is never set to true, so your if clause after the second for loop is always executed. So every row should return a mismatch. I guess "eRequest ID" is located on sheet one in column 2 and on sheet 2 in column 7?

Comment: -EngJon the "eRequest ID" is located on column 1 on both sheets. Is there a way to make this code simpler as well??

Comment: One more thing, I just realized that this code only copies rows from `Sheets("JULY15Release_Master Inventory")` It doesnt copy rows from `Sheets("JULY15Release_Dev status")` even if there is only one "eRequest ID" for that data.

Answer (score 0):

Your "eRequest ID" are located in both sheets in column A so I compare this column. If there is a match in both sheets the loop exists. If there is no match then the row get copied to "mismatch". loop for both sheets.

```
Sub compareAndCopy()
   Dim lastRowMaster As Integer
   Dim lastRowDev As Integer
   Dim lastRowMis As Integer
   Dim foundTrue As Boolean

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    lastRowMaster = Sheets("JULY15Release_Master Inventory").Cells(Sheets("JULY15Release_Master Inventory").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    lastRowDev = Sheets("JULY15Release_Dev status").Cells(Sheets("JULY15Release_Dev status").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    lastRowMis = Sheets("Mismatch").Cells(Sheets("Mismatch").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    'start loop Master
    For i = 2 To lastRowMaster '1 = headers
    foundTrue = False
    For j = 2 To lastRowDev

    If Sheets("JULY15Release_Master Inventory").Cells(i, 1).Value = Sheets("JULY15Release_Dev status").Cells(j, 1).Value Then
        foundTrue = True
        Exit For
    End If

    Next j

    If foundTrue = False Then
    Sheets("JULY15Release_Master Inventory").Rows(i).Copy Destination:= _
    Sheets("Mismatch").Rows(lastRowMis + 1)
    lastRowMis = lastRowMis + 1

    End If

    Next i
    'end loop master

    Sheets("Mismatch").Cells(lastRowMis + 2, 1).Value = "results from Dev"
    lastRowMis = lastRowMis + 2

    'start loop Dev
    For i = 2 To lastRowDev '1 = headers
    foundTrue = False
    For j = 2 To lastRowMaster

    If Sheets("JULY15Release_Dev status").Cells(i, 1).Value = Sheets("JULY15Release_Master Inventory").Cells(i, 1).Value Then
        foundTrue = True
        Exit For
    End If

    Next j

    If foundTrue = False Then
    Sheets("JULY15Release_Dev status").Rows(i).Copy Destination:= _
    Sheets("Mismatch").Rows(lastRowMis + 1)
    lastRowMis = lastRowMis + 1

    End If

    Next i
    'end loop dev


    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean by same formatted? I changed my IF statement to yours, and it displays the same result..

Comment: One more thing, I just realized that this code only copies rows from `Sheets("JULY15Release_Master Inventory")` It doesnt copy rows from `Sheets("JULY15Release_Dev status")` even if there is only one "eRequest ID" for that data.

Comment: btw... may i know what is the value **2** in `Sheets("JULY15Release_Master Inventory").Cells(i, 2).Value ` for?? Likewise, **7** in `Sheets   ("JULY15Release_Dev status").Cells(j, 7).Value`

Comment: Sorry to say but I'm only an intern doing this macro for my company. My company is very strict on all their files, I'm blocked from uploading it on sites like google drive, dropbox etc; nor can I take the file out and do it with my own PC, as the file is encrypted. Is there another way we can do this? Without sharing my excel files.. Really sorry though, I would love to share it and get this settled ASAP as well.

Comment: so create a new excel with sample data of your 2 worksheets and copy&paste the values of the 2 worksheets in your first post by editing it. It's hard to answer your questions without that sample

Comment: What I mean is that I can't share any files from my office computer at all, nor can I take these files home and share it with my own PC as the files would be encrypted. I have however taken some pictures, which are [this](http://imgur.com/S9lwigG) and [this](http://imgur.com/cxPctGS) that shows some of the data. The first one is for my Master Inventory worksheet, and the second is for Release Dev Status. Hope this helps, and I am thankful that you are taking the time and effort to do this. Cheers!

Comment: Ok, I meant to copy only the data in your edit, not to upload a file. As I see on your pics there are more questions: What to you exact need? You write you need "eRequest ID" but those are on both sheets in column A, your code looks for "CR Type" so I'm confused.

Comment: I need to copy the rows of data that **ONLY HAVE 1 "eRequest ID"** that exists in either sheets, not both. You can check out the codes Ron did [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30090517/vba-copy-rows-after-comparing-column-data/30091678#30091678) It managed to copy **SOME OF THE ROWS** but there were still rows missing, not copied over. Hope this clarify your doubts, feel free to ask if you need to!

Comment: so look if your "eRequest ID" exist in both sheets and if exist only in one sheet then copy to mismatch? Is that right?

Comment: Yup thats right! The whole row of data has to be copied over though, from their respective worksheet. It would be great if **the rows from Master Inventory** could be copied over first, followed by a **blank row** to act like a spacing. Then copy the **rows from Release Dev Status** over. Appreciate your help!

Comment: I just tried out your codes, and the only thing that appeared in `Sheets("Mismatch")` is "results from Dev". Apparently the value in this line `Sheets("Mismatch").Cells(lastRowMis + 2, 1).Value = "results from Dev"` is not being carried over.

Comment: I meant the value from the original two worksheets, not that line, sorry my mistake.

Comment: the code is working fine with my test data. `Sheets("Mismatch").Cells(lastRowMis + 2, 1).Value = "results from Dev"` is just a gimmick, you can delete if you want. Try to debug the code or make a copy of your file with just some entries for easier debugging. Also clear your filters

Comment: I tried both clearing the filers, and running the macro with filters and its still not working... The code is running fine without bugs though.

Comment: Unfortunately without testfile or debugging error I can't help you. Tried the code again with more data and runs fine

Comment: @JunJie Feel free to mark my answer as your solution if it helped you

Comment: Hey katz, it's solved already. [Here's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30090517/vba-copy-rows-after-comparing-column-data/) the link if you want to check it out!