# VBA Excel copy rows based on column

Tags: excel, vba, comparison

I'm trying to create a macro which copies rows of data after comparing a column value. I previously asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30050485/excel-vba-compare-column-data-copy-row) but made some progress, and thought it would be less confusing if i posted another question. The column to be compared is "eRequest ID" and it consists of integers and text.

I have two worksheets, both with "eRequest ID" as the first column. The goal here is to copy **ANY** rows of data that has an "eRequest ID" **NOT FOUND** in both worksheets. Meaning if this record's "eRequest ID" is only found on one worksheet and not both, the whole row of data has to be copied into a third new worksheet.

I have worked out some codes after browsing through the net, and with the help of the coding experts here. The problem with this codes is that somehow I get a "mismatch" for every row. I tried changing the `foundTrue` value here and there but it doesn't seem to work. I need it to only copy rows of data with only **1 "eRequest ID"** on either worksheet. Greatful for any help and appreciate your effort!

```
Sub compareAndCopy()

Dim lastRowE As Integer
Dim lastRowF As Integer 
Dim lastRowM As Integer
Dim foundTrue As Boolean

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

lastRowE = Sheets("JULY15Release_Master Inventory").Cells(Sheets("JULY15Release_Master Inventory").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
lastRowF = Sheets("JULY15Release_Dev status").Cells(Sheets("JULY15Release_Dev status").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
lastRowM = Sheets("Mismatch").Cells(Sheets("Mismatch").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To lastRowE
foundTrue = True
For j = 1 To lastRowF

'If Sheets("JULY15Release_Master Inventory").Cells(i, 2).Value = Sheets("JULY15Release_Dev status").Cells(j, 7).Value Then
 If Sheets("JULY15Release_Master Inventory").Cells(i, 2).Value <> Sheets("JULY15Release_Dev status").Cells(j, 7).Value Then
    foundTrue = False
    Exit For
End If

Next j

If foundTrue Then
Sheets("JULY15Release_Dev status").Rows(i).Copy Destination:= _
Sheets("Mismatch").Rows(lastRowM + 1)
lastRowM = lastRowM + 1

End If


Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

End Sub
```

Comment: I just found out that ALL the data in `Sheets("JULY15Release_Dev status")` can be found in `Sheets("JULY15Release_Master Inventory")`, so maybe the comparison part can be ignored. Only rows with an "eRequest ID" **NOT FOUND IN** `Sheets("JULY15Release_Master Inventory)` needs to be copied over to `Sheets("Mismatch"). Also, by editing the above code, I managed to copy the rows that are only found in `Sheets("JULY15Release_Dev status")`  but some rows in `Sheets("JULY15Release_Master Inventory)`  are copied along as well.. Hope this helps, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it should work, **TESTED**.

```
Sub test()

Dim lrow1 As Long
Dim lrow2 As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim K As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim p As Variant
Dim wb As Workbook

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
K = 2
lrow1 = wb.Sheets("JULY15Release_Master Inventory").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lrow2 = wb.Sheets("JULY15Release_Dev status").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To lrow1

p = Application.Match(wb.Sheets("JULY15Release_Master Inventory").Range("A" & i).Value, wb.Sheets("JULY15Release_Dev status").Range("A1" & ":" & "A" & lrow2), 0)
If IsError(p) Then
        wb.Sheets("JULY15Release_Master Inventory").Rows(i).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Mismatch").Rows(K)
        K = K + 1
End If
Next

For j = 1 To lrow2
p = Application.Match(wb.Sheets("JULY15Release_Dev status").Range("A" & j).Value, wb.Sheets("JULY15Release_Master Inventory").Range("A1" & ":" & "A" & lrow1), 0)
If IsError(p) Then
        wb.Sheets("JULY15Release_Dev status").Rows(j).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Mismatch").Rows(K)
        K = K + 1
End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey there, I cant add another column as there is some format with my table.. Is there another way to do this without adding a new column? @Vasily answer seems pretty close, but it is still copying the wrong rows. Perhaps you can figure this out? Thank you!

Comment: Hey there, thanks for helping out. I'm getting a subscript out of range error however, on this line `p = Application.Match(Sheets("JULY15Release_Dev status").Range("A" & j).Value, Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1" & ":" & "A" & lrow1), 0)` Would you fix it and get back to me? Really thankful :)

Comment: Replace Sheet1 with your sheet name. replace Sheet1 = 'JULY15Release_Dev status' and sheet2 = 'JULY15Release_Master Inventory' however you need

Comment: I just changed the Sheet names accordingly, but when I run the code nothings happening

Comment: It is working for me, you might need to trace at each step, where it is going wrong for you

Comment: what do you mean by "trace"? Sorry i'm a total novice at this I dont really get some of the jargons used here. Btw, I mentioned I couldn't add another column due to my file's nature.. Would that be a problem? If so, can we work another way around this?

Comment: press F8 on and see the result, however just try the edited code with your sheet names.

Comment: I just tried the edited code, its working without error but nothing's happening. I tried tracing, but it kept repeating at the **first for loop**, not moving onwards. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

another one variant

```
    Sub test()
    Dim lastRowE&, lastRowF&, lastRowM&, Key As Variant
    Dim Cle As Range, Clf As Range
    Dim DicInv As Object: Set DicInv = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dim DicDev As Object: Set DicDev = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = 0

    lastRowE = Sheets("JULY15Release_Master Inventory").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    lastRowF = Sheets("JULY15Release_Dev status").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    lastRowM = Sheets("Mismatch").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    'add into dictionary row number from Inventory where cell is matched
    For Each Cle In Sheets("JULY15Release_Master Inventory").Range("A1:A" & lastRowE)
        If Cle.Value <> "" Then
            For Each Clf In Sheets("JULY15Release_Dev status").Range("A1:A" & lastRowF)
                If UCase(Cle.Value) = UCase(Clf.Value) Then DicInv.Add Cle.Row, ""
            Next Clf
        End If
    Next Cle
    'add into dictionary row number from Dev where cell is matched
    For Each Clf In Sheets("JULY15Release_Dev status").Range("A1:A" & lastRowF)
        If Clf.Value <> "" Then
            For Each Cle In Sheets("JULY15Release_Master Inventory").Range("A1:A" & lastRowE)
                If UCase(Clf.Value) = UCase(Cle.Value) Then DicDev.Add Clf.Row, ""
            Next Cle
        End If
    Next Clf
    'Get mismatch from Inventory
    With Sheets("JULY15Release_Master Inventory")
        For Each Cle In .Range("A1:A" & lastRowE)
            If Not DicInv.exists(Cle.Row) And Cle.Value <> "" Then
                .Rows(Cle.Row).Copy Sheets("Mismatch").Rows(lastRowM)
                lastRowM = lastRowM + 1
            End If
        Next Cle
    End With
    'Get mismatch from Dev
    With Sheets("JULY15Release_Dev status")
        For Each Clf In .Range("A1:A" & lastRowF)
            If Not DicDev.exists(Clf.Row) And Clf.Value <> "" Then
                .Rows(Clf.Row).Copy Sheets("Mismatch").Rows(lastRowM)
                lastRowM = lastRowM + 1
            End If
        Next Clf
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = 1

    End Sub
```

**Sample**

`JULY15Release_Master Inventory`

[image]

`JULY15Release_Dev status`

[image]

**Output Result**

`Mismatch`

[image]

Comment: Hey there! Thanks for your help, the code is working fine and all, copying data from both worksheets. However, it is still copying the rows with data that has "eRequest ID" on both worksheets. I need the rows that only have an "eRequest ID" on **EITHER WORKSHEET*. Perhaps it has something to do with the **Range values**? I'm not sure, I'm a total beginner at this. Could you help me out? Thank you very much!

Comment: @JunJie could you please provide data sample?

Comment: Sure thing, how do I do it though? Not sure how things work around here.. Is there a feature that let me share files with you??

Comment: @JunJie post has been updated, please recheck again, I think that problem was in case when `"A" = "a"` not matched due to Upper case not equal lower case

Comment: I just tried the edited code.. It makes no difference though, is there any way I can share the files with you?

Comment: @JunJie  please see my updated post with screenshots, is this what you trying to achieve?

Comment: I took two pictures.. the links are [this](http://imgur.com/S9lwigG) and [this](http://imgur.com/cxPctGS) these two pictures show my **Inventory** and **Release** worksheets. I need to copy the records that have an "eRequest ID" **IN EITHER WORKSHEETS NOT BOTH**. For example, the record with "eRequest ID of 41275 exists in both worksheets, therefore i dont need to copy it.

Comment: i tried that earlier on, but when I run the code nothing happens.

Comment: @JunJie as per your screenshots I see that criterias for matching in column "A" for both sheets, so the range in code has been updated, please recheck again.

Comment: Yup, I copied the edited codes over, but when I run it nothing is happening.

Comment: @JunJie please share your file with google drive or using another resource

Comment: I'm sorry but the company I'm working for is very strict with their files.. We are blocked from google drive, dropbox, social media platforms and similar websites. The files would also be encrypted if i were to remove it and I don't have permission to do so as I'm only an intern. Is there another way we can do this? Sorry to bother you but I really need to get this done. Thank you!