# VBA copy rows after comparing column data

Tags: excel, vba, comparison

Okay hi everyone, again. So I have already posted several similar questions but to no avail.. I decided to post another one as I think it would be pretty messy to keep commenting below. The links for my previous questions are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30050485/excel-vba-compare-column-data-copy-row/30051134?noredirect=1#comment48262434_30051134) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30066702/vba-excel-copy-rows-based-on-column)

I decided to try and change @Vasily codes as his provides the closest results. Please click the second link to view his original codes if need be.

So my original problem was to compare data from 2 worksheets, both which includes an "eRequest ID" column in "A". I need to copy the rows of data with only 1 "eRequest ID" on **EITHER FILES into a new worksheet** This means that data with existing "eRequest ID" on **BOTH FILES** can be ignored.

So here are the edited codes based on Vasily and it runs fine, without errors. However, what it does now is copy **ALL ROWS OF DATA** from both worksheets, its not filtering according to the "eRequest ID", which is what I need.

```
Sub test()

Dim lastRowE&, lastRowF&, lastRowM&, Key As Variant
Dim Cle As Range, Clf As Range                         'Cle for Master Inventory, Clf for Release Dev Status

Dim DicInv As Object                                   'DicInv for Master inventory, DicDev for Release Dev Status
Set DicInv = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

Dim DicDev As Object
Set DicDev = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")


Application.ScreenUpdating = False

lastRowE = Sheets("JULY15Release_Master Inventory").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
lastRowF = Sheets("JULY15Release_Dev status").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
lastRowM = Sheets("Mismatch").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'add into dictionary row number from Inventory where cell is matched
For Each Cle In Sheets("JULY15Release_Master Inventory").Range("A1:A" & lastRowE)
    If Cle.Value <> "" Then
        For Each Clf In Sheets("JULY15Release_Dev status").Range("A1:A" & lastRowF)
            If Cle.Value = Clf.Value Then DicInv.Add Cle.Row, ""
        Next Clf
    End If
Next Cle
'add into dictionary row number from Dev where cell is matched
For Each Clf In Sheets("JULY15Release_Dev status").Range("A1:A" & lastRowF)
    If Clf.Value <> "" Then
        For Each Cle In Sheets("JULY15Release_Master Inventory").Range("A1:A" & lastRowE)
            If Clf.Value = Cle.Value Then DicDev.Add Clf.Row, ""
        Next Cle
    End If
Next Clf
'Get mismatch from Inventory
With Sheets("JULY15Release_Master Inventory")
    For Each Cle In .Range("A1:A" & lastRowE)
        If DicInv.exists(Cle.Row) Then 'And Cle.Value <> ""
            .Rows(Cle.Row).Copy Sheets("Mismatch").Rows(lastRowM)
            lastRowM = lastRowM + 1
        End If
    Next Cle
End With
'Get mismatch from Dev
With Sheets("JULY15Release_Dev status")
    For Each Clf In .Range("A1:A" & lastRowF)
        If DicDev.exists(Clf.Row) Then 'And Clf.Value <> ""
             .Rows(Clf.Row).Copy Sheets("Mismatch").Rows(lastRowM)
            lastRowM = lastRowM + 1
        End If
    Next Clf
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

In both my previous questions, I was asked to share my files so that the gurus here could help out. Unfortunately, I am unable to do so as I am simply an intern working for my current company. They are very strict with their files, encrypting any file that is taken out of the office. We are also blocked sites such as Google Drive and DropBox.. Unless if you guys have another method to share these files, (which I would gladly comply!!!!!) I only managed to take these two pictures and post it on imgur.

This [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tofrN.jpg) shows the data in my first worksheet, Master Inventory and this [image](https://imgur.com/cxPctGS) shows the data in my second worksheet, Release Dev Status.

Hope this helps, and I am very sorry that I'm not able to provide more information. Thankful for your help so far, cheers to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Your pictures show that the Data is in Tables; and that these are filtered.  Do you only want to consider the filtered results, or the entire table?  Do you have the names of these tables?

Comment: @ron Yup i filtered these out beforehand, only the filtered results need to be considered. I plan to add another few line of codes after recording the filtering step as a macro. And what do you mean by **names of tables?** Sorry, I'm very new to this and there's many terminologies I'm unfamiliar with!

Comment: OK so we will completely ignore the rows that you have hidden.  So far as the table names, the data is in a Table, and the table has a name.  When you create a Table in Excel, Excel will give it a name, but the name can be changed by the user.  Hint:  Look up `Create a Table` in `HELP`.  Also, if you look at the top right of the ribbon, you will see a tab that says `Table Tools`.  Under the tab it says `Design`.  If you click there, you will get information about the table.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Ah I think I got it! It should be "Table_JULY15Release_Master_Inventory__2" and "Table_JULY15Release_Dev_status__2" Are these what you're looking for?

Comment: @RonRosenFeld Hope it helps, been stuck on this problem for days now..

Comment: It seems simple to solve, but the devil is in the details.  And it's late here, so not sure how much longer I will have.

Comment: @Ron Rosenfeld If it helps, I think the problem currently lies in the For loop, where the IF condition is not specfic enough I suppose. As the current code is able to add every row into dictionary and then copy it into `Sheets("Mismatch")` Would you be able to solve this?? Really grateful you took the time and effort to reply.

Comment: I'll use different code.  And is it the case that for the MisMatch results you just need the eRequest ID and the Worksheet Tab?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Nope, I need to select the whole row of data if there is only one "eRequest ID". For example, in both my pictures, there is a record of "41275" in both worksheets. Thus, this row of data need not be selected. Records with "eRequest ID" such as "41239" which can **only be found in 1 worksheet** needs to be selected and copied over to the new worksheet tab. Hope this clarify your doubts! Thank you.

Comment: That is different than what you showed in one of your examples.  And if you want to copy over the entire row, how do you want to handle the problem that the row headers are not identical on the two sheets?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Hmm, I'm not exactly sure what you mean.. but these are two pictures I took, showing what the current code does. [this](http://imgur.com/12tnQux) and [this](http://imgur.com/afIoRUt) The rows are copied from their original worksheet, with all data intact. The rows from **Master Inventory* are copied first, followed by **Release Dev Status**. For eg, if record "41239" were to be copied, the entire row would be copied under "Release Dev Status" Does this help? Feel free to ask more if you need clarifications!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still not sure what you want to do with the different sheets.  But the following macro will copy the rows that are not present in both sheets to the MisMatch worksheet.  The Inventory rows are copied first, then a blank line, then the Dev rows.  Probably need some formatting to pretty things up, and other stuff could be added.

I use both a Class module and a Regular module.
After you Insert the Class module, you must **rename the class module:  cMismatch**

It'll probably need some modifications.  And I'll be happy to answer questions in the morning.

**Class Module**

---

```
Option Explicit
Private pID As String
Private pWS As String
Private pRW As Range

Public Property Get ID() As String
    ID = pID
End Property
Public Property Let ID(Value As String)
    pID = Value
End Property

Public Property Get WS() As String
    WS = pWS
End Property
Public Property Let WS(Value As String)
    pWS = Value
End Property

Public Property Get RW() As Range
    Set RW = pRW
End Property
Public Property Set RW(Value As Range)
    Set pRW = Value
End Property
```

---

**Regular Module**

---

```
Option Explicit
Sub MisMatches()
    Dim cMM As cMisMatch, colMM As Collection
    Dim vInv As Variant, vDev As Variant
    Dim vMM() As Variant
    Dim wsINV As Worksheet, wsDEV As Worksheet, wsMM As Worksheet
    Dim loINV As ListObject, loDEV As ListObject
    Dim rINV As Range, rDEV As Range, rMM As Range
    Dim I As Long


Set wsINV = Worksheets("JULY15Release_Master Inventory")
Set wsDEV = Worksheets("JULY15Release_Dev Status")
Set wsMM = Worksheets("MisMatch")

'If there is more than one table on the worksheet, will need to
'  use a better ID
Set loINV = wsINV.ListObjects(1)
Set loDEV = wsDEV.ListObjects(1)


'get the data ranges, visible (unfiltered rows) only
Set rINV = loINV.DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
Set rDEV = loDEV.DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

'place the filtered rows into arrays
vInv = VisibleDataTable_To_Array(rINV)
vDev = VisibleDataTable_To_Array(rDEV)

'collect the mismatches, using the Collection object
'collect all the items from first WS, then remove them if they are also on second
Set colMM = New Collection
For I = 1 To UBound(vInv)
    Set cMM = New cMisMatch
    With cMM
        .ID = CStr(vInv(I).Cells(1, 1))
        .WS = wsINV.Name
        Set .RW = vInv(I)
        colMM.Add cMM, .ID
    End With
Next I

On Error Resume Next
For I = 1 To UBound(vDev)
    Set cMM = New cMisMatch
    With cMM
        .ID = CStr(vDev(I).Cells(1, 1))
        .WS = wsDEV.Name
        Set .RW = vDev(I)
        colMM.Add cMM, .ID
        If Err.Number = 457 Then
            colMM.Remove (.ID)
            Err.Clear
        End If
    End With
Next I
On Error GoTo 0

'write the results

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
wsMM.Cells.Clear
Set rMM = wsMM.Cells(2, 1)
For I = 1 To colMM.Count
    Select Case colMM(I).WS
        Case wsINV.Name
            colMM(I).RW.Copy rMM(I)
        Case wsDEV.Name
            colMM(I).RW.Copy rMM(I + 1)
    End Select
Next I

With wsMM.UsedRange
    .ClearFormats
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Function VisibleDataTable_To_Array(rng As Range) As Variant
    'assumes all areas have same columns
    Dim rwCNT As Long
    Dim I As Long, J As Long, K As Long, L As Long
    Dim V() As Variant

    rwCNT = 0
    For I = 1 To rng.Areas.Count
        rwCNT = rwCNT + rng.Areas(I).Rows.Count
    Next I
    ReDim V(1 To rwCNT)

    K = 0 'array row counter
    For I = 1 To rng.Areas.Count
        For J = 1 To rng.Areas(I).Rows.Count
            K = K + 1
            Set V(K) = rng.Areas(I).Rows(J)
        Next J
    Next I
    VisibleDataTable_To_Array = V

End Function
```

---

Comment: Hey Ron, I tried out your code and it's working fine so far without errors. However, there are still a few problems.. Firstly, I get the part where you collect all the items from first WS, and then remove them if there are duplicates on the second. This part is working fine, except some rows are still left out. Secondly, the data seems a little off after being copied over to the new worksheet. I'll snap a few pictures and post it in my next comment so it's easier for you to see.

Comment: Okay regarding the picture.. I cant crop it with anything to make it easier for you to see with my office's computer.... Really sorry, but basically what I'm trying to say is that, there are some columns with data not copied over. There are a total of about 20+ columns for every row, and the first few columns are being copied fine. The columns that are not copied over mainly consists of data that are in date/time format. Hope this helps you and I really appreciate your help. Sorry if I'm making things confusing, no idea how to show it to you as I cant share the files, nor take a proper picture

Comment: Hey ron, I just realized that I didn't add the `Option Explicit` line in... i tried it out already and it seems to be copying the exact number of incorrect rows (unless i missed out). However, the data for each row is still incomplete, like what I mentioned earlier, the columns at the back are not copied over. These columns mainly consists of data in date/time format. Hope this helps, thank you!

Comment: @JunJie Are the columns in question part of the Table?

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean by "question part of the table"? and heres some example.. [this](http://imgur.com/0qchLoe) shows the data in **Release Dev Status**, the one to be copied. And [this](http://imgur.com/GCUq97z) shows the one that is being copied, in `Sheets("Mismatch)"` The date/time value seems to be off.

Comment: Ah shucks, I just got what you mean. Yes they are part of the table.

Comment: You wrote that some columns are not being "copied over".  But your example seems to only show possible dates that are not formatted.  What do you mean by "copied over"?

Comment: I think its just the date values format.. I went to unfilter the Inventory and Dev worksheet and it seemed fine now. Just that the date values are not formatted correctly, is there a way to fix this??

Comment: Just remove the `.ClearFormats` line.  But you may have to decide how you want the results to look

Comment: It's working great!! Thanks a bunch Ron, you're a lifesaver. Really grateful you took the time to answer all my questions.. and solving this as well. :)

Comment: Glad we got it to work.  In the area where the `.ClearFormats` line was, you can add other parameters to make it look pretty, if you want or need to.

Comment: Hey Ron, I just got a new problem... My boss wants me to change the sheet. from **"JULY15Release_Dev Status" to
"JULY '15 Rel"** and JULY'15 REL has two tables in it.. I'm currently facing a run-time error 9, subscript out of range on this line. `Set loDEV = wsDEV.ListObjects(1)`, where you put a comment "If there is more than one table on the worksheet, will need to use a better ID". Is this causing the problem??

Comment: Yes it is. You will have to set it to the proper table

Comment: Okay hang on, it actually isn't a table at all.

Comment: Maybe it is not really a Table

Comment: Yes, I formatted it as a table and it's working fine now.. I have another task to do now though. I have to **create two new colums in Release Dev Status** and populate it with data from **JULY `15 Rel** if their "eRequest ID" matches. Do you know how to do this?? Really sorry to trouble you..

Comment: @JunJie You should have the tools to be able to assemble code to do this.  Examine the code I supplied so you can see and understand the steps involved.  You should then be able to use a similar approach for your new task, by looking for appropriate matches and using that as the data to be kept.  Once you've done that, if you have problems, post a question with your new code and someone will help.  SO is not a free code-writing service.  It exists to help others learn how to do these things themselves.  Important if you are going to be developing/maintaining code for your boss.

Comment: Will do Ron, I'm asked to try VLOOKUP function for now, and i'll ask if I have any queries. Really thankful for your help in solving this issue though! :)